# Unable to override LocaleResolver bean in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization

I have a pure REST spring boot application, which I'm trying to inject my own implementation of the AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver class:

```
public class SmartLocaleResolver extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver implements InitializingBean {
@Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
         // Some code...
    }
}
```

And I'm injecting the bean like so:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement()              
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "app.core.i18n" })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

    @Autowired
    private FhngHibernateInterceptor interceptor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                ;
            }

            @Bean
            public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
                SmartLocaleResolver slr = new SmartLocaleResolver();
                slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));
                return slr;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

However, no matter what I do, my own resolveLocale() method is *never* called. I set a breakpoint inside DispatcherServlet::initLocaleResolver() to confirm this:

```
private void initLocaleResolver(ApplicationContext context) {
    try {
        // This always throww the NoSuchBeanException
        this.localeResolver = context.getBean(LOCALE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME, LocaleResolver.class);

        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
        // We need to use the default.
        this.localeResolver = getDefaultStrategy(context, LocaleResolver.class);

    }
```

The bean is never found so a default stragety is used.

What might be missing?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `LocaleResolver` bean outside of your `WebMvcConfigurer` bean.

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SmartLocaleResolver slr = new SmartLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));
        return slr;
    }
```

The *locale* of your bean (pardon the pun) will not be picked up by Component Scanning if you define it there.